# Angular 2 Multiple Http GETs where responses map to classes

Tags: angular2-services

I have a 2 classes called car and lorry.

I have API URLs cars.com and lorries.com which return an array of objects in JSON.

I have a service which has 2 variables:
cars: car[]; 
lorries: lorry[];

In the service I need a function called getData() which should call both API URLs at the same time and map the response to either cars or lorries arrays.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should in general **not** use classes to represent the data returned by the API for this scenario. It is misleading to use a class just to specify the type of an object which is not created by that class and which was actually created by `JSON.parse`. Interfaces should be used for this scenario.

That aside, you can accomplish your goal in a relatively straightforward manner

**vehicle.service.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/add/Observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

import {Car, Lorry} from './resources';
import injected from './injected';

@injected export default class VehicleService {

  constructor(readonly http: Http) {}

  getCarsAndLorries(): Observable<(Car | Lorry)[]> {
    return Observable
      .forkJoin(this.getCars(), this.getLorries())
      .merge();               
  }

  getCars() {
    return this.http.get('api/cars')
      .map(response => response.json() as Car[]);
  }

  getLorries() {
    return this.http.get('api/lorries')
      .map(response => response.json() as Lorry[]);
  }
}
```

**resources.ts**

```
export interface Car {
  miles: number;
  make: string;
  doors: 2 | 4;
  drive: 'fwd' | 'rwd'| '4wd';
  ...
}

export interface Lorry {
  miles: number;
  make: string;
  card: Product[];
  ...
}

// you get the idea....
export interface Product {
  name: string
  ....
}
```

**injected.ts**

```
/**
 * c the newable being decorated
**/
export default function (c: new (...args: any[]) => {}) {
  console.info('type metadata is emit is triggered by any decorator');
  return c;
}
```

**app.module.d.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import VehicleService from './vehicle.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [VehicleService]
}) export default class {}
```

Comment: Why use custom decorator `@inject`? Why not `@Injectable()`? Will the `Http` class be injected without `@Injectable()`?
forkJoin is very neat. But why use `.merge()` after forkJoin?

Comment: Are used to custom decorator because most people don't know that any decorator will cause the type annotations to be injected into the source code.

Comment: Fork join fires off the requests in parallel Kama which is a nice way to reduce latency when operations are independent. Are used much because your question seemed to indicate that you wanted I sort of get data method that returned everything. It was my interpretation of your question which was not particularly specific. You can project the results of combined requests into many different configurations